# Python BeautifulSoup: get specific element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div class="new_info_next">
     <input type="hidden" value="133" id="new_id" class="new_id">
     <input type="hidden" value="0" id="default_pe" class="default_pe">
</div>
```

and I want to get only `133` in `input`.

Here is how I did it using [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) version 4:

```
info = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "new_info_next"})
for inpu in info:
    for inpu1 in inpu.select('input'):
         print inpu1 .get('value')
```

but the output was:

```
133
0
```

How do I get only `133`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want the first element in the iterator, addressing it directly should work:

```
first = inpu.select('input')[0].get('value')
print(first)
```

Comment: I strongly believe my answer is more efficient than this.  This *finds all matching elements*, then gets the first of all of those, mine simply grabs the first one that matches.

Comment: @northsideknight find() is implemented by calling find_all() internally in BSoup, and find_all() is a generator - so my guess is that the difference is perfectly negligible when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 9):

use
    soup.find()

by default it will get you the first element matching, so you could do:

```
info = soup.find("div", {"class": "new_info_next"})
```

and info.get('value') should be 133