# Python3 beautifulsoup4 - getting input value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

1、Post the main page
2、Enter the first content
3、in children page get the next  content

I found the hidden article property.BUT I can't get the actually value.
I try to find all things get the input value , but it doesn't work.
[Similar question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187731/python-beautifulsoup-get-specific-elment)

```
import bs4,requests,os

url = 'http://www.qiushibaike.com'
#request the main page
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

qsMain = soup.select('a[class="contentHerf"]')[0]
print(qsMain)
url = 'http://www.qiushibaike.com' + qsMain.get('href')

#enter the first content
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
print(url)
subLink = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

#get Children page 
s = subLink.select('input')[0].get('value')
print(s)
s1 = subLink.find("div", {"class":"article block untagged noline mb15"})
print(s1)
```

[here the INPUT I want find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Ciq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
subLink.select('input')[0]
```

In particular your choice to just get `[0]`. There are many `input` elements and the one you want is not the first. The first is `<input id="hid" type="hidden">`, close to the top of `s1`.

To reliably find the correct tag, just use its `id`, like so:

```
s = subLink.find(id="articleNextLink").get('value')
```

Comment: I had try this method, But I found the value not the 'article/118839782' is the random value. like 'article/118743286'

Comment: @Nomiki yes, the value is random. Open https://www.qiushibaike.com/article/119222287 and look at the hidden input value. Now open the article again in a new private browsing window (so there are no cookies) and you will see the value changes. They track visitors to try and make the links consistent but they're random. `requests.get` creates a new session each time which is why it always changes.

Comment: Thanks in deep!!! 
This problem has troubled me for a long time.Thank you so much!